# static public And public static, Why the same thing can be done in two different styles?

Tags: java

```
static public final int i = 0;
public static final int i = 0;
```

Both working fine.
Why the same thing can be done in two different styles?

Comment: You can mix the keywords in any order... Not just public static, also e.g. (methods) `final synchronized strictfp private void main()`. **Whatever you decide to do, be consistent!**

Comment: Because if not, you will ask why not.

Comment: To quote the [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1) : _"If two or more (distinct) class modifiers appear in a class declaration, then it is customary, though not required, that they appear in the order consistent with that shown above in the production for ClassModifier"_

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because there is no reason to block it.

Neither operator has any precedence or effect on the other, you can put all the keywords before the variable (for example volatile as well) in any order. That's just the way the language is defined.

The general style tends be to have access level first, then static if present, then anything else. That's not even an official guideline though (that I know of), just what most people do.

Answer (score 3):

The [Java Language Specification, Section 8.3.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.3.1), allows it:

> FieldModifiers:
>
> ```
> FieldModifier
> FieldModifiers FieldModifier
> ```
>
> FieldModifier: one of
>
> ```
> Annotation public protected private
> static final transient volatile
> ```

This restriction:

> It is a compile-time error if the same modifier appears more than once in a field declaration, or if a field declaration has more than one of the access modifiers public, protected, and private.

and

> If two or more (distinct) field modifiers appear in a field declaration, it is customary, though not required, that they appear in the order consistent with that shown above in the production for FieldModifier.

So, `public static` and `static public` are allowed.

Comment: Yeah, I +1d both these answers for that reason :)

Answer (score 1):

From section 8.3.1 (Field Modifiers)of the Language Specification:

"If two or more (distinct) field modifiers appear in a field
declaration, it is customary, though **not required**, that they
appear in the order consistent with that shown above in the
production for FieldModifier."
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/classes.html#78091

So the answer is: It's a language specification